# main function return will not return high integer

Tags: c++, return

I have this as my program and I want to call that program:

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);
    return x;
}
```

I call that program with another program and give it an int argument.
It works good when x is low but lets say x = 1000 then it returns a low number

Comment: What OS/compiler are you working with?

Comment: In Unix-land the `exit` function argument is limited to an 8-bit byte. In Windows you have 32 bits, but one particular value (which means process still running) that you must avoid just above the byte value range.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I think it *is* a duplicate, but although Jerry's answer is very nice it's incomplete for Windows.

Comment: With GCC 4.9.0 is working as expected. Returning high values OK.

Comment: @NetVipeC: on which OS? I just tested on my Linux/Debian/Sid with GCC 4.9.1 and it does not work as you say (because of well known reasons explained in answers)

Comment: I'm sure you (NetVipeC) are wrong. Ubuntu is a Linux, and Linux don't handle exit code about 255.....

Comment: Using GCC don't mean that i'm using Linux (is a probable guess, but no a certain one), tested in Win8.1, MinGW with GCC 4.9.0 compiling with C++11, there is no indication in the question about Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Posix and Unix systems the return value of `main` matters mostly as 0 (i.e. `EXIT_SUCCESS`)  vs non zero (e.g. `EXIT_FAILURE` i.e. 1) -and as others are explaining, only the lower byte matters. This is what every shell can handle very easily (e.g. with its `if` or its `&&`); to get the exit code in a shell you otherwise need `$?`

BSD systems have some dozen of (single byte) *conventional* exit codes in `<sysexits.h>` (but Linux *usually* don't follow these conventions).

On Unix systems the good way to "return" an integer `i` from a program is to *output* it (in textual form, i.e. with `printf("%d\n", i);` ...) to *stdout*.  The the invoking program (a shell or something else) could read that. In a C program it is quite easy to use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (with `pclose`) or more generally learn about [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s

<sup>My personal dream would be to have program returning some *string* as their exit value, but this won't happen soon and require changes in OS and compilers and languages....</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The `main` return value is passed to the `exit` function.

The `exit` function's argument is declared as an `int`, and you can legally pass any `int` value to it. On UNIX-like systems, all but the low-order 8 bits of the argument are quietly ignore. For example, `exit(INT_MAX);` is perfectly legal, but it's equivalent to `exit(255);` (or `exit(-1);` for that matter).

In Windows you have 32 bits, but one particular value (`STILL_ACTIVE` = 259 which means process still running) that you must avoid just above the byte value range.

---

The C++ standard defines just three possible values: **0** (which means success), **`EXIT_SUCCESS`** and **`EXIT_FAILURE`**, the latter two macro symbols from `<stdlib.h>` (where also the `exit` function is declared).

In Unix-land and Windows `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined as 0, which is allowed by the standard.

Unfortunately, in Windows, where it's common to use the process exit code to communicate a low level error code, `EXIT_FAILURE` is typically/always defined as 1 instead of as `E_FAIL`. Which means that even for a program documented as returning an error code or `HRESULT` as exit code, you have to beware of the value 1. It's possibly just `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Comment: Not *quite* accurate. The `exit()` function's argument is of type `int`, and; in Unix-land, all but the low-order 8 bits are ignored. It's perfectly legal to call `exit(INT_MAX)`, but it's equivalent to `exit(255)`.

Comment: @KeithThompson: thanks, I didn't think of that (that it mattered). Will rewrite. OK, done.

Comment: Your second paragraph (now edited) still says that the argument is *limited* to an 8-bit byte value range, which implies that passing a value outside that range is somehow invalid.

Comment: @KeithThompson: well, can you fix it? i not master words this english luangage! thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by `main` is actually just a single unsigned byte. The high bits are used for other things (special status flags).

At least on UNIX and UNIX-like systems (like Mac OSX and Linux). See e.g. the [official POSIX reference for the `wait` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).